# How to set CacheControl in the new Cloud Storage Api (Python)?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm following the guidelines and updating my code to use the new Cloud Storage API in GAE, i do need to set the cachecontrol headers, previously it was easy:

```
files.gs.create(filename, mime_type='image/png', acl='public-read', cache_control='public, max-age=100000, must-revalidate' )
```

BUT, with the new API, the guidelines says that the "cache_control" is not available...
I get this error when tried to put the cachecontrol inside the Options:

```
ValueError: option cache_control is not supported.
```

Tried with Cache-Control and the same error...

As usual, the documentation of the new API is not good.

Can someone help me how to set the cache headers in the new Cloud Storage API using PYTHON.  In case is not possible, can I still use the old api for my project?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are right. As documented [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/functions#open), 
the open function only supports x-goog-acl and x-goog-meta headers.

Cache control is likely to be added in the near future to make migration easier. Please note that the main value of the GCS client lib is buffered read, buffered resumable write, and automatically retries to overcome transient errors. Many other simple REST operations on GCS (e.g cache, file copy, create bucket ...) can already be done by Google API [Client](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/libraries). The "downside" of Google API Client is that since it doesn't come directly from/for App Engine, it does not have dev appserver support.

Comment: I tried to modify the source code of the new cloudstorage client api, in the common.py i added the CacheControl...  _GCS_OPTIONS = ('x-goog-acl','x-goog-meta-','Cache-Control') and that worked fine for the CacheControl, now is recognized and set.  But the "Expires" header is wrong, it set a default time of two hours after the creation date and I can't be able to change it... Do you know if it's possible to change or eliminate the "Expires" header in this new client api?  THANKS!

Comment: First of all, "Expires" header is not set by the new client api. It is set by GCS server on responses. From my experiment, GCS set expires to epoch for PUT and POST responses. For read, GCS set expires correctly from max-age, e.g. I created a file on 5:22 PST with max-age=6000 and expires is set by GCS to be 02:02 GMT

Comment: Thanks, the Expires are working when setting the cache control date!  I have a question for U, what's your recommendation to get mi file edge cached by google and other proxies, use "no-transform" or "must-revalidate" in the cache control (besides public, maxage=....)? THANKS!

Comment: depending on the type of your files, the answer can be very different. see a good guide here. http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/